# Ionic 2 giving wrong response while making post request with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ionic2

I'm doing login from an app using php and mysql. When I put the URL on the browser with credentials appended with it, if the credentials are valid, it prints correct response like `success:true`. If credentials are not valid, it prints `success:false`. But when I put do ionic serve and do a login from the app, it prints `success:true` on console all the time, even if the credentials are not valid.

This is my IONIC-2 code:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept",'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
let postParams={
  username: logincreds.username,
  password: logincreds.password,
}
this.http.post("http://vaishalishaadi.com/AppLogin.php", postParams, options)
  .subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(postParams);

    console.log(data);     
    /*if(data.json().success=="success"){

    } 
    else{

    }  */
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Following code is of PHP:

```
  header('Content-type: application/json');
if($check){  
        session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $check->u_id;
    $_SESSION['u_name'] = $check->u_firstname;
             $login_response=["success"=>"true"];
              //print(json_encode($login_response));
            //echo $check->u_id;
                $data[] = array(
                    'pram'=$username
            'id' => $check->u_id,
            'fname' => $check->u_firstname,
            'lname' => $check->u_lastname,
        );
        $result = "{'success':true, 'data':" . json_encode($data) . "}"; 

    }
    else{
      $result = "{'success':false}";
   }
   echo($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found Solution Over It**
**Just changed the way I was passing parameters and also removed 'options' argument from post request.**

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('username',logincreds.username);
params.append('password',logincreds.password);
this.http.post(url, params)
  .subscribe(data=>{
console.log(postParams);

console.log(data);     
/*if(data.json().success=="success"){

} 
else{

}  */

}, error => {
console.log(error);
})
```

**Use URLSearchParams instead of using array to collect parameters being passed to server**